# error: not found: value in scala command wordcount

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

I am trying run some scala code in spark following an online video tutorial: it's a wordcount program

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/data/mr/wordcount/big.txt")
val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(s => (s.toLowerCase(), 1))
val counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
counts.take(10)
```

[image]

```
<console>:24: error: not found: value counts
   counts.take(10)
   ^
```

and it's the same error whenever I run ever command that does not start with val

Comment: That is pretty weird since `counts` was defined in the previous line. Maybe all the lines failed? Try running line by line and confirm each one work as expected.

Comment: I did but I get the same error

Comment: What did the **REPL** printed when you executed the line `val counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)` ?

Comment: this is a screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1afoZPuCh_x9BugAqK2OSiwJFBLWUmc2H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link is private, also it would be better if you can just edit the question with all those details as plain text.

Comment: Well, you now can see that creating `counts` failed, so it doesn't exist... and the reason it failed was because the file you read didn't exist.